# Oracle Service Bus (11.1.1.6.0): <xsd:include> issue

Tags: include, osb

IF I use this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="Chick">
   <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="count" type="xsd:decimal" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

With this wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="test"
xmlns:chi="chick"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test/">
        <xsd:include schemaLocation="testschema.xsd"></xsd:include>
        <xsd:include  id="ada" schemaLocation="testschema.xsd" />
        <xsd:element name="doTheRightThing">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="Chick" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="doTheRightThingResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="out" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="doTheRightThingRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:doTheRightThing" name="parameters" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="doTheRightThingResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:doTheRightThingResponse" name="parameters" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="test">
    <wsdl:operation name="doTheRightThing">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:doTheRightThingRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:doTheRightThingResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="testSOAP" type="tns:test">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="doTheRightThing">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://www.example.org/test/doTheRightThing" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="test">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:testSOAP" name="testSOAP">
        <soap:address location="http://www.example.org/" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

I get this error message:

**Error building the Schema Type system for the WSDL:
D:\Oracle\Middleware_11.1.1.6.0\user_projects\domains\osb_cookbook_domain\test:0: error: src-resolve.a: Could not find element 'Chick'. Do you mean to refer to the element named Chick@http://www.example.org/test/ (in testschema)?**

If I change this line in wsdl:

```
 <xsd:element ref="Chick" />
```

to this:

```
 <xsd:element ref="tns:Chick" />
```

I could not deploy, OEPE returns this error message:

**The WSDL is not semantically valid: error: src-resolve: element 'Chick@http://www.example.org/test/' not found..**

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch 14003546 solved this issue:

**WSDL WITH EMBEDDED SCHEMA INCLUDE TO NO-NAMESPACE FAILS VALIDATION**